# Update series of numeric values in long string

Tags: regex, string, postgresql, sql-update

I have text column with following examplary data:

```
5,5,0.1;6,6,0.15;7,7,0.2;8,8,0.25;9,9,0.3;10,10,0.35;11,11,0.4;12,12,0.45;13,13,0.5;14,14,0.55;15,15,0.6;16,16,0.65;17,17,0.7;18,18,0.75;19,19,0.8;20,20,0.85;
```

I need to add some fixed value to each of numeric values (the one before semicolon)
so for example from:

`5,5,0.1;6,6,0.15`; I want add 0.15 so result would be:

```
5,5,0.25;6,6,0.3;
```

I guess I should try something with regexp_replace but I have no idea how to start here

Comment: This is a horrible database design. Do you have a chance to fix that? With a properly normalized model this would be a very simple UPDATE statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution would be fix your broken data model and not store multiple, delimited values in a single column.

---

I wouldn't do this with a regex, but unnesting the elements of the string, adding the value to the third element, then aggregate everything back into the broken design:

```
update badly_designed_table
  set denormalized_column = 
       (select string_agg(concat_ws(',', a, b, round(c + 0.15,2)), ';' order by idx)
        from (
          select split_part(val, ',', 1) as a,
                 split_part(val, ',', 2) as b,
                 split_part(val, ',', 3)::numeric as c,
                 idx
          from unnest(string_to_array(bad_column, ';')) with ordinality as x(val,idx)
           -- skip the "empty" element generated by the trailing ;
          where nullif(val, '') is not null
        ) t)
```

Comment: I'm aware this structure is terrible but unfortunately I can't change it as its part of old architecture still used by some applications. However your query works just perfect, thank you!